# sheaf of differentials definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about the definition of the sheaf of differentials:
If $\Delta$:X$\rightarrow$X$\times$X is the diagonal morphism then $\Delta$ is a locally closed immersion.

If we take $I$ to be the ideal sheaf of $\Delta$(X), we use $I/I^2$ to define sheaf of differentials.

What exactly do we mean by $I/I^2$?

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear what you are asking, but there is a point about which one can get easily confused: The sheaf of differentials is not $I/I^2$, but $\Delta^* (I/I^2)$ - indeed, the first thing is a sheaf on $X \times X$, not on $X$ itself.

Note that this is necessary for anything to be well-defined: As you noted correctly, $\Delta$ is not necessarily a closed immersion. This means that the ideal sheaf $I$ is not a sheaf on $X$, but rather on some open neighborhood of the diagonal, which you have to *choose* - this is not reflected in the notation, because the resulting sheaves become isomorphic after pulling them back to $X$.

As a final remark, differentials are fundamentally a relative notion - everything in your post and my answer should be taken as relative to a map $f: X \to Y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Actually i did not say that the sheaf of differentials is $I$/$I^2$.I said we use this and as you mentioned i exactly mean what you said the :pullback of $I$/$I^2$.If i want to be more clear i want to know that by the sheaf $I$/$I^2$ we mean we the sheafification of a pre-sheaf which assign to each open set $U$ the quotient $I$($U$)/$I^2$($U$)? i know my question is a little strange but i asked this because i dont know if $I^2$ itself is sheaf or no!we consider $I^2$ as a pre-sheaf then we do sheafification or no $I^2$ is itself a sheaf?

Comment: Ah, it was unclear to me what you asking. You certainly get the right answer if you sheafify at each step. Whether the presheaf defined by $U \mapsto (I(U))^2$ is already sheaf or not is an interesting question though, you might want to put this explicitly in your OP.

Comment: So you mean it is correct to consider  $I$/$I^2$ as pre-sheaf and then do sheafificatio?

Comment: Yes. Note that the 'associated sheaf' functor from modules to quasi-coherent sheaves is exact, so this sheafification changes nothing on affine opens, only on non-affine ones. This is what makes the comparison with the module of differentials in the ring world easy.